# drupal php: problem with hosting a new drupal site

Tags: php, drupal, hosting

I am a newbie to drupal.
I try to host  it on a free hosting (german) kilue.de.(apache, mysql5.0)
To test what I have done locally , on the site :
1- I create the database using phpmyadmin
2 -I copied what I have under /var/ww using FTP

Once I launch my site using given uurl , I have this message :

```
* warning: realpath() [function.realpath]: open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/tmp) is not within the allowed path(s): (/data/multiserv/users/395147/projects/730411:/var/tmp/multiserv/users/395147/projects/730411:/data/apache/users/kilu.de/agbsite) in /data/multiserv/users/395147/projects/730411/www/includes/file.inc on line 190.
* warning: realpath() [function.realpath]: open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/tmp) is not within the allowed path(s): (/data/multiserv/users/395147/projects/730411:/var/tmp/multiserv/users/395147/projects/730411:/data/apache/users/kilu.de/agbsite) in /data/multiserv/users/395147/projects/730411/www/includes/file.inc on line 787.
* warning: tempnam() [function.tempnam]: open_basedir restriction in effect. File() is not within the allowed path(s): (/data/multiserv/users/395147/projects/730411:/var/tmp/multiserv/users/395147/projects/730411:/data/apache/users/kilu.de/agbsite) in /data/multiserv/users/395147/projects/730411/www/includes/file.inc on line 787.
* warning: fopen() [function.fopen]: Filename cannot be empty in /data/multiserv/users/395147/projects/730411/www/includes/file.inc on line 788.
* The file could not be created.
* warning: realpath() [function.realpath]: open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/tmp) is not within the allowed path(s): (/data/multiserv/users/395147/projects/730411:/var/tmp/multiserv/users/395147/projects/730411:/data/apache/users/kilu.de/agbsite) in /data/multiserv/users/395147/projects/730411/www/includes/file.inc on line 190.
* warning: realpath() [function.realpath]: open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/tmp) is not within the allowed path(s): (/data/multiserv/users/395147/projects/730411:/var/tmp/multiserv/users/395147/projects/730411:/data/apache/users/kilu.de/agbsite) in /data/multiserv/users/395147/projects/730411/www/includes/file.inc on line 190.
* warning: realpath() [function.realpath]: open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/tmp) is not within the allowed path(s): (/data/multiserv/users/395147/projects/730411:/var/tmp/multiserv/users/395147/projects/730411:/data/apache/users/kilu.de/agbsite) in /data/multiserv/users/395147/projects/730411/www/includes/file.inc on line 787.
* warning: tempnam() [function.tempnam]: open_basedir restriction in effect. File() is not within the allowed path(s): (/data/multiserv/users/395147/projects/730411:/var/tmp/multiserv/users/395147/projects/730411:/data/apache/users/kilu.de/agbsite) in /data/multiserv/users/395147/projects/730411/www/includes/file.inc on line 787.
* warning: fopen() [function.fopen]: Filename cannot be empty in /data/multiserv/users/395147/projects/730411/www/includes/file.inc on line 788.
* The file could not be created.
* warning: realpath() [function.realpath]: open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/tmp) is not within the allowed path(s): (/data/multiserv/users/395147/projects/730411:/var/tmp/multiserv/users/395147/projects/730411:/data/apache/users/kilu.de/agbsite) in /data/multiserv/users/395147/projects/730411/www/includes/file.inc on line 190.
```

Can anyone help me to find out what is the problem?

Answer (score 6):

Your web host does not allow you to access the default Drupal temporary file location, `/tmp`.

You can go to `admin/settings/file-system` and change the temporary file location to something you do have access to. I'd create a folder called `tmp` in your user directory and target that location instead. You may need to set permissions via CHMOD on it so the webserver can write to it.

In your particular case try setting it to

```
 /var/tmp/multiserv/users/395147/projects/730411.
```

It must be a folder your open_basedir setting permits.

Comment: I change my tmp as indicated but I still have the same problem.

Comment: @agb Try setting it to `/var/tmp/multiserv/users/395147/projects/730411`. It must be a folder your `open_basedir` setting permits.

Comment: this worked for me. thank you very much, your answer was very clear.

Comment: +1 Good answer. Also check check correct path for Temporary directory /tmp in admin/config/media/file-system
On my live production hosting for my site, this is /tmp - which appears to be the default BUT on my local development setup (using a WAMP stack (ZWAMP)), this is just tmp - without the preceding slash /
The explanation would be that /tmp represents some other place on my machine - perhaps C:\tmp rather than a subpath on my docroot. Obviously this is something to remember when uploading the development back to the internet as this setting needs to be changed back.

Answer (score 0):

It would appear there is an open_basedir restriction in effect.